# ADF Sharepoint API (HTTP) Conncection Wildcard File

Tags: sharepoint, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have an http connection to a sharepoint db and I would like to import a file without having to specify the file name. Is it possible?

Currently I use a dataset that has parametrized the url to this @concat('dburl/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(',dataset().filename, ')/$value')

filename is a parameter that i have defined

In my pipeline I have the copy activity get the token and the appsecret and I just specify in the filename parameter the name. I tried using the symbol * and everything else but it fails.

Comment: Hi, there is a comma missing in the expression after dataset().filename. Can you try after correcting the expression `@concat('dburl/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(',dataset().filename, ')/$value')`

Comment: Hello, I fixed I can still use it but I have to specify again the File name in the path in order to get the file, is it possible to for example write something like this '/path1/*' to get the file?

Comment: Alternatively, could you try to get the filenames using get metadata activity and pass the filename to the dataset parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In order to download/copy the files from Sharepoint you will have to pass the filenames and you cannot use wildcards naming. Hence you will have to follow the below series of steps to achieve it.

1. Web1 – Get the access token from SPO.
2. Web2 – Get the list of files
3. From SPO folder ForEach1 – Loop the list of file names
4. Copy1 – Copy Data with HTTP connector as source

For details steps, please refer to this article by an MSFT engineer - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/sharepoint-online-multiple-files-folder-copy-with-http-connector/ba-p/2480426